# Keras Training warm_start

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, keras

Is it possible to continue training a Keras estimator with all the hyperparameters (including decreasing learning rate) and weights saved from previous epochs, as one does in scikit-learn with the `warm_start` parameter? Something like this:

```
estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_model, epochs=20, batch_size=40, warm_start=True)
```

Specifically, warm start should do this:

> warm_start : bool, optional, default False When set to True, reuse the
>   solution of the previous call to fit as initialization, otherwise,
>   just erase the previous solution.

Is there anything like that in Keras?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes - it's possible. But rather cumbersome. You need to use [`train_on_batch`](https://keras.io/models/model/#train_on_batch) function which keeps all model parameters (also optimizer ones).

This is cumbersome because you need to divide your dataset to batches on your own and you are also losing the possibility to apply [`Callbacks`](https://keras.io/callbacks/) and to use automatic `progbar`. I hope that in new `Keras` version this option would be added to a `fit` method.

Comment: Wow that is definitely annoying. I hope they add that

Comment: Yes. We are thinking about implementing it on our own because it probably wouldn't need many changes in `Keras` code.

Comment: If it works well, consider making a pull request! After some more searching this seems like a commonly requested feature

Comment: Is there an update on this?